# Updating Labels on a second View Controller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, button, label

I have several different `ViewControllers` set up in my project. The first one acts as a 'landing' page and and on pressing a `button` the `view` is directed to a following `ViewController`.

There are various buttons and `labels` on there that I want to use to provide information and run a method. The buttons all work ok, but I have followed every tutorial I can to get the labels to update based on a method, and I can't seem to get them to do so.

I know the methods are called correctly as I have put print statements in there to check.

Basic idea is, program plays a series of beeps separated by a delay (bleep_time), this changes each level (bleep_level) and there are several steps (bleep_step) in each level. Ive simplified the arrays containing this data to save space.

I have successfully created a number of tutorial projects and the labels all update correctly, but they only use one ViewController.

Is the issue I am facing due to using 2 `ViewControllers`?

`ViewController` 1

```swift
import UIKit

class Bleep_Test_Menu: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
}
```

View Controller 2

```swift
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class Bleep_Test_Level_1: UIViewController {    

    // Global Variables
    var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer?

    // Bleep test delays
    var bleep_time = [1,2,3,4]

    // Levels of bleep test
    var bleep_level = [1,2,3,4]

    // Level Label
    @IBOutlet weak var bleepTestLevel1Level: UILabel!        

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()        
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    // Function to run repeated bleeps
    @IBAction func bleepTestLevel1Start(_ sender: Any) {

        var i = 0

        tracker = false
        let length = bleep_time.count

        while i < length {

            var bleeplevel = bleep_level[i]
            bleepTestLevel1Level.text = "\(bleeplevel)"
            playSaveSound()
            sleep(UInt32(bleep_time[i]))

            i += 1
        }
    }

    // Function to play sounds
    func playSaveSound(){
        let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Sound1.wav", ofType: nil)!
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)

        do {
            //create your audioPlayer in your parent class as a property
            audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
            audioPlayer?.play()
        } catch {
            print("couldn't load the file")
        }
    }
}
```

The only error I keep getting in the console is this;
"Tests[53616:891478]  - changing property contentsGravity in transform-only layer, will have no effect"
But I can't seem to find anything that relates to my issue.

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to have any issue that will cause that error. Cause I guess we are focusing on the error you are getting rigth? And how to solve it, right? If so, can you post a screenshot of Bleep_Test_Level_1 storyboard and also show the Attribute Inspector in the screenshot for views such as your label?

Comment: Using segue you can send information from one view to another

Comment: Here is a link to the helper tutorial https://learnappmaking.com/pass-data-between-view-controllers-swift-how-to/

Comment: Thanks for the replies, I have isolated just that one ViewController and tried re-running the code and still doesn't update the labels, so I can't work out why as it is more or less the same code used in most tutorials. It does seem to have removed the error though so that might have been associated with a different controller.

@denis_lor: hopefully this link works for the screenshot; [link](pasteboard.co/IrU8pMM.png)

LearningPhase: Im not actually even trying to send the variable between the view controllers, they are staying on the same one as the view and button click.

Comment: if you want controller 1 and controller 2 to interact with each other maybe what you mean is protocol and delegate, maybe this reference can help

https://medium.com/swift2go/passing-data-between-viewcontrollers-via-delegate-protocols-4ecde4b167de